# create user provider with FOSOAuthServer in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, symfony, oauth

I have implemented oAuth on my Symfony App with FosOAuthSeverBundle.

Now I want to use my existing user Repository on mongoDB and extend it to use authenticate user via a FOSOAuth Interface. Is there an interface and methods similar to this oAuth User Provider in this question:

[How can I write a user provider for HWIOAuthBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26760059/2420289)

Comment: Usually you don't have end-users log into MongoDB. The authentication of end-users should be handled by the application. The user management mechanism of MongoDB is meant for the application itself and for the database administrators to authenticate themselves.

Comment: the point is i would like to authenticate via flow password. I fixed it on the service declaration for my user provider using  `factory_service: doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager`